# Java force static field inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, static, field, final

I have already searched for quite an amount of time to get a solution to this but none of them were comfortable enough to be acceptable.

Let's say we have an abstract class and all its subclasses shall provide a static and final field.

```
abstract class A {
    static final Field FOO;
}

class B extends A {
    static final Field FOO = new Field("foo");
}
```

It's like this: There shall be instances of B and I don't want them to have a getter which means I would have to make an abstract method but there I have the same problem again.

Getter:

```
abstract class A {
    static final Field FOO;
    public Field getFOO() { return A.FOO; }
        // This method is not that great as I need it to be static.
        // Also, as it refers to class A, but if I want to let B inherit this method it won't refer to B.FOO.
    public static Field getFOO() { return FOO; }
        // This method is not inherited due to being static.
        // Because it is not inherited, it can't be what I want.
}
```

What can I do to force the subclasses having a static final field with a specific name (and a set value) I have access to when adressing class A?

In fact, all I want is to do the following:

I have an abstract class that is called `Component`. I want to make a program that gets other classes from plugins. These classes shall inherit some fields and methods from `Component`. They shall also be forced to have a static ID. The question is now: How do I force classes (that are provided by plugins) to have such a field?

Comment: Sounds like you need an interface.

Comment: Your situation is unclear. The code you have given will not compile (because you have not given a value to `FOO` in `A`). Furthermore it's not clear what abstract class and what subclasses you are talking about because neither classes in your code is abstract, nor is it a subclass of anything but `Object`. Can you give a code example that actually shows the situation you are facing? And what getter you are talking about that you want to avoid?

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it, since again, your approach is likely wrong.

Comment: I concretised what I wrote after I read your justified criticism.

Comment: why does the field have to be static?

Comment: The user may create his/her own classes but I restrict them to inherit from `Component`. As there shall be instances of these custom classes and I don't want redundance, I want to make this value static.
Also: The next option would be to make an abstract Field (which is not possible afaik) and the option after that would be to make the field just a normal one.

Comment: “I don’t want to use `foo`, but `bar` instead. How can I make `bar` behave like `foo`?”

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how to force a Java comiler to check this at compile time,
but it can be done at runtime, using Reflection API:

```
public class MyClassA {

    static final Integer foo = 123;

    public MyClassA(){
        try {
            Field f = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("foo");
            int fooModifiers = f.getModifiers() ;
            if( fooModifiers != ( Modifier.FINAL | Modifier.STATIC ))
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Each subclass of MyClassA must declare a field: static final Integer foo = value");
            }
        } catch ( SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( NoSuchFieldException e ){
            throw new RuntimeException("Each subclass of MyClassA must declare a field: static final Integer foo = value", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ... x){
        MyClassA m = new MyClassA();
    }
}
```

---

And now an object of a subclass of MyClassA cannot be instatiated without first declaring a field in this subclass: `final static Integer foo`:

```
public class MyClassB extends MyClassA{

    public static void main(String ... x){
        MyClassB m = new MyClassB();
        System.out.println("I am main");
    }

    // final Integer foo = 444;
    // final private Integer foo = 444;
    static Integer foo = 555;
    // static final Integer foo =333;
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would fullfill the purpose I intented but reflection slows the code down. As I might need this to be checked only during instantiation I might create dummy-classes that use reflection and then use subclasses of them. Could this be a good idea?